# Is there any OpenID Connect Identity Provider that can delegate autentication to other OpenID Connect IdPs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito, keycloak, openid-connect, okta

I'm facing the following scenario:

There are several companies each one with its own OpenID Connect Identity Provider (IdP) which federates users from their respetive LDAP servers. These providers are used to perform SSO in the context of each company.

There's a requirement to create an application that offers a common login for all the users of those companies.

The idea is to provision or use an existing cloud solution (AWS Cognito, Google Cloud Identity, etc., ...) that offers a shared login screen but delegates/federates the actual login to each of the company IdPs.

Are there any solutions that allows this?
Could you point at any documentation/guide to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just standard OAuth and OpenID Connect behaviour, with these 3 roles:

- Application, uses OIDC to redirect to ...
- An Authorization Server, which you own, and which redirects to ...
- An Identity Provider

So you need a standards based authorization server and to configure your app as an OAuth Client. Then include the `openid` scope so that OpenID Connect is used. SAML based identity providers can also be supported in this flow, even though your app only uses OIDC.

The way to manage this with best usability, is for the authorization server to present a `usernane authenticator`, which captures a user identifier first, such as an email. It then runs some custom logic, such as a user lookup, to determine which IDP to route the user to. The user then authenticates at the IDP.

After authentication, the IDP issues tokens to the authorization server, which validates them, then issues its own tokens to the application. In particular the app gets an access token whose scopes and claims you can control. Your app can then send these to your APIs, which can authorize access to business data correctly.

Aim for behaviour similar to that above, or adjust it based on your preferences. Then trial it, eg with a cloud or Docker based authorization server, and ensure that you select one with sufficient extensibility to meet your requirements.

Note also that Stack Overflow answers should not recommend particular vendors, so I have not done so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution called [cloudpods](https://github.com/yunionio/cloudpods) using which you can manage both on-prem and public cloud resources. Cloudpods supports integration with multiple cloud providers like aws, GCP, azure, alibaba and etc.,

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any OpenID Connect Identity Provider that can delegate autentication to other OpenID Connect IdPs?

Yes. https://github.com/apereo/cas is one. You can set it up as an OIDC identity provider and have it then delegate to as many OIDC Identity providers as you want.